# Elegant Management of Duplicate rss items from C# SyndicationFeed

Tags: c#, duplicates, rss, feed

This question is about advice on a good approach for a novice c# programmer. I have a simple and working bit of code to grab RSS news items, that I want to process each RSS item only once. The "news grab" (ie working code below) is on a timer.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(defaultNewsURL)) {
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items) {               
        // do a task I only want to do once per item
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest an elegant way of tracking the items so that as it refreshes, I don't constantly process the same items gain and again, but only the new ones as they dribble in? I have tried a few (that work) but they all look ugly to me...

Ta, Ed

Comment: Serialise each item to a string. Store them in a `HashSet` (using `Add`). If `Add` returns `true` they are new.

Comment: @user2057357 Also, you could parse those items with a `Syndication.SyndicationItem.PublishDate`  which is `>` of `DateTime? _LatestUpdate = YourItemsCollection.Max(x => x.PublishDate);`. Or check the last entry, since those items are probably already ordered by date.